# XMLIgnore: Remove base class properties from child class nodes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am using XMLIgnore property to remove unwanted properties at serialization. But I want to remove some base class property from child class only. I want property from base class but it should not repeat in child class node.

**Is it possible to remove base class properties from child class nodes?**

In my code I am getting output below format: When I am removing property from base class through XMLIgnore.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InformationCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <projects>
    <Project xsi:type="Group">
      <GroupName>Accounts</GroupName>
      <Comment>Financial Transaction</Comment>
    </Project>
  </projects>
</InformationCollection>
```

But actually I am expecting output below Format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InformationCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <projects>  
      <ProjectId>1</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>HRMS</ProjectName>
      <Project xsi:type="Group">
         <GroupName>Accounts</GroupName>
         <Comment>Financial Transaction</Comment>
    </Project>
  </projects>
</InformationCollection>
```

I am trying this by below code:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Group))]
    public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public Project() { }
        public Project(int projectId, string projectName)
        {
            ProjectId = projectId;
            ProjectName = projectName;
        }
    }
    public class Group : Project
    {        
        public string GroupName;        
        public string Comment;
        public Group():base() { }
        public Group(int projectId, string projectName)
            : base(projectId, projectName)
        {

        }
        public Group(int projectId, string projectName, string groupName, string comment)
            : this(projectId, projectName)
        {
            GroupName = groupName;
            Comment = comment;
        }
    }
    public class InformationCollection
    {
        public List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();
        public InformationCollection()
        {
            projects.Add(new Group(1,"HRMS","Accounts","Financial Transaction"));
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerializeObject("IgnoreXml.xml");
        }

        public static XmlSerializer CreateOverrider()
        {
            XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
            attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
            xOver.Add(typeof(Project), "ProjectName", attrs);
            xOver.Add(typeof(Project), "ProjectId", attrs);
            XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InformationCollection), xOver);
            return xSer;
        }

        public static void SerializeObject(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xSer = CreateOverrider();
                InformationCollection informationCollection = new InformationCollection();                
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
                xSer.Serialize(writer, informationCollection);
                writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have control of both the base and derived classes, you can do this with `XmlSerializer` by adding a virtual [`bool ShouldSerializeXXX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for each property `XXX` for which you wish to control output.  In the base class, make method should return `true`, and in the derived class, it should be overridden to return `false`.

For instance, say you want to suppress serialization of the `Id` property in a derived class only, you can do:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeId()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class DerivedFromBaseClass : BaseClass
{
    public override bool ShouldSerializeId()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, to test:

```
    public static void TestSuppressingPropertyInDerivedClass()
    {
        var baseClass = new BaseClass() { Id = 31 };
        var derivedClass = new DerivedFromBaseClass { Id = 31 };

        var baseXml = baseClass.GetXml();
        // Xml looks like 

        Debug.Assert(baseXml.Contains("Id")); // No assert
        var derivedXml = derivedClass.GetXml();
        Debug.Assert(!derivedXml.Contains("Id")); // no assert.
    }
```

The output XML for the `BaseClass` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<BaseClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>31</Id>
</BaseClass>
```

And for `DerivedFromBaseClass`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DerivedFromBaseClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

As you can see, `Id` has been suppressed in the XML for the derived class only, which is, I think, what you are requesting.

As an aside, however, I think your object model here may not be ideal.  If you have properties in the base class that should not appear in a derived class, that suggests you should extract a more general, abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractProject {
{
    // Properties common to "Group" and "Project"
}

public class Project : AbstractProject {
{
    // Properties specific to Project
}

public class Group : AbstractProject {
{
    // Properties specific to Group
}
```